# CLICK function is OK but ON CHANGE is not working on multi selectbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my code of JQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //code for validation
    $("#categoryid").on("change", function() {
        var categoryid = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo site_url('user/order/getItem') ?>",
           data: {'categoryid': categoryid},
           cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              $("#itemid").html(data);
           } 
       });
    });

    $("#itemid").on("change", function() {
        var itemid = $(this).val();

        alert(itemid);

    });
});
```

The first one (#categoryid) is working well. but the second one (#itemid) is not working. If i change the "change" to "click" it works but i am surprised why it is not working on "change" function.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Select Category:</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="categoryid" autofocus>
       <?php
       $url = site_url('user/category/showCategoryJson'); // path to your JSON file
       $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
       $results = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON feed
       foreach ($results[0] as $key => $cat) { 
       ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $cat['categoryid']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['categoryname']; ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
       </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Select Item:</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="itemid">
     </select>

 </div>
```

Here is my controller-

```
public function getItem(){
    $data = array(
        'categoryid' => $this->input->post('categoryid')
    );

    $this->load->model('user/order_model');
    $res = $this->order_model->selectItem($data);

    if($res){           
        foreach ($res as $result) {
            echo "<option value=". $result['itemid'].">".$result['itemname']."</option>";
        }
    }

}
```

and the output picture-
[image]

Comment: try to add some option values..

Comment: Yes already i did.. it is not working :(

Comment: Yes @ShadowFiend right. You don't have option in select box. Add some option there.

Comment: @user3311692 how many have you added? if its only one then it won't work.

Comment: Options are coming from my controller using ajax.

Comment: `<select class="form-control" id="itemid">` does not appear to be multi select.  can you please post the markup that's being rendered by your ajax request?

Comment: Can you please show your controller function by which you are getting option using ajax.

Comment: @user3311692 does the results in ajax displays in the page?

Comment: Yes i have added the controller and the output picture

Comment: @user3311692 do you seen any error?

Comment: No error occurred, it works fine if i change it to click function

Comment: Have you tried with a delegated event (`$(document).on('change','select#itemid',function() { ... })`)? It shouldn't be necessary here because you are not generating the `select` dinamically, but at least give it a try to see what happens and if it give us some information.

Comment: @A.Iglesias no change the result same

Comment: And in the browser inspector the console is completely clean, right? No errors, no warnings... nothing? It's really strange, it should work (https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/gLm7c2mj/). Add a couple of `option` manually to that `select` in your php (so you don't have to change the first select to get the options) and then change the value to see if you get the `alert`.

Comment: you can trigger an event using `$("#itemid").trigger("change");`

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your success ajax call

```
              $.each(data,function(i,data){
                  $("#itemid").append($('<option>', {
                        value : data,                                       
                        text : data
                    }));    
             })
```

Comment: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <option value=36>a</option>

Comment: Before adding to the option into your select tag ,just print the argument(data) of success ajax function call using `console.log(data)` because of the argument have value or not

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#itemid',function(){

})
```